# Как выбрать элемент из List и отобразить его в ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, textbox, listbox

У меня есть две формы. На первой форме (Form1) располагается ListBox1, на второй (Form2) - несколько TextBox'ов.

На второй форме пользователь вводит необходимые данные о товаре (название товара, город производителя и тд) и затем нажимает кнопку "добавить". Все введенные данные записываются в List (MyList).

**Вопрос в следующем:** как после ввода на первой форме в ListBox1 отобразить только название товара?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам примерчик
[image: пример работы программы]

Раз вы работаете с сущностью типа `Товар`, то и нужно создать ее класс

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Код основной формы такой

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //источник данных для ListBox
    private BindingSource _bsProducts;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Пример ввода данных и  их отображения";

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();

        //
        _buttonAddProduct.Click += ButtonAddProduct_Click;
        _buttonRemoveProduct.Click += ButtonRemoveProduct_Click;
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _bsProducts = new BindingSource();
        _bsProducts.DataSource = typeof(List<Product>);
        //
        _listBoxProducts.DataSource = _bsProducts;
        _listBoxProducts.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);
        //
        _textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsProducts, nameof(Product.Name));
        _textBoxCity.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsProducts, nameof(Product.City));
        _textBoxPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsProducts, nameof(Product.Price));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Добавить
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = "<?>",
            City = "<?>",
            Price = 0
        };

        var inputForm = new FormInputProduct(product);
        inputForm.Owner = this;
        inputForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        inputForm.Text = "Новый товар";

        if (inputForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _bsProducts.Add(product);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Удалить
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonRemoveProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bsProducts.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

Код формы ввода такой

```
public partial class FormInputProduct : Form
{
    //Редактируемый продукт
    public Product Product { get; }

    public FormInputProduct(Product product)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Product = product ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(product));

        //назначаем кнопкам результаты
        _buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        _buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.CancelButton = _buttonCancel;
        this.AcceptButton = _buttonOk;

        this.Load += FormInputProduct_Load;
    }

    private void FormInputProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //привязки
        _textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", Product, nameof(Product.Name));
        _textBoxCity.DataBindings.Add("Text", Product, nameof(Product.City));
        _textBoxPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", Product, nameof(Product.Price));
    }
}
```

Пример целиком можно глянуть и скачать [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsListBox).

Comment: Еще хотел уточнить, если я в дальнейшем буду добавлять на форму еще один textbox, в котором будет показана новая цена со скидкой, то это нужно реализовывать в `private void SetBindings()` в главной форме?

Comment: Да, и видимо, не только на главной, но и в окне ввода нового продукта.